Finger print generating different Ids
I have been using https://fingerprint.com/ in my project for fingerprint identification. Now I have a requirement that I need to generate fp in two ways:

When a user hits a BFF endpoint (in which case it would return a link). I'm generating and returning a HTML script which contains the fingerprint

There's another endpoint which lets you invoke a script on the client side.


Now both of these consistently return different fingerprintID (they independetly remain same) for the same browser and client.
What are the ways I can try? I tried creating same method in both the case (i,e fp.load() and fp.get() ) without any results.
P.S I'm testing the client side script on local.
Hers's the code that would execute on the client side:
window.myFunc = async (options) => {
    const fp = await FingerprintJS.load({
        monitoring: false
    });
    const { visitorId } = await fp.get();

    const data = {
        origin: options.origin,
        fingerprint: visitorId,
        tenant: options.tid
    };

    
};

Here's a route that would return a script containing the fingerprint:
function getHtmlScript(callbackURL) {
    log.debug(`dirname ${__dirname}`);
    const filePath = path.join(__dirname, '../../public/static/js/htmlScript.js');
    log.debug(`filepath ${filePath}`);

    // eslint-disable-next-line no-sync
    let htmlScript = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8');
    htmlScript = htmlScript.replace('`callbackEndpoint`', callbackURL);

    return `<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <script> 
                ${htmlScript}
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        </body>
    </html>`;
}

